# header file in include path of gcc not detected

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld, include-path

I have installed a library ([libxc](http://www.tddft.org/programs/libxc/)) into a local directory (`./configure --prefix=$HOME/materials/mat`). I changed the environmental variables appropriately but I get the following error when compiling a test code that includes libxc:

```
(mat) amir@bose test]$ gcc test_libxc.cc
test_libxc.cc:3:10: fatal error: xc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xc.h>
          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

But `xc.h` is located in `/home/amir/materials/mat/include` directory:

```
(mat) [amir@bose test]$ ls /home/amir/materials/mat/include/
libxc_funcs_m.mod   python3.6m/         xc_f03_lib_m.mod    xc_f90_lib_m.mod    xc_f90_types_m.mod  xc_funcs.h          xc_funcs_removed.h  xc.h                xc_version.h
```

which is in the gcc's list of directories for search (fifth line below):

```
(mat) [amir@bose test]$ echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/gcc/7.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/amir/materials/mat/include
 .
 /opt/gcc/7.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/gcc/7.3.0/include
 /opt/gcc/7.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

I could not understand this behavior. If you have any idea what may be the problem, please do share with us.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -al /home/amir/materials/mat/include/xc.h` and where are you specifying `-I/home/amir/materials/mat/include` as part of your compile string or as part of an environment variable?

Comment: did you try compiling with the `-I` option just to see if yoy really configured it right?

Comment: Could there be a space or something (carriage return, `\r`?) after the `/home/amir/… path that is preventing it working?  Which environment variable did you set, and how did you set it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin output of `ls -al ` is: `-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 11152 2018-08-31 11:24 /home/amir/materials/mat/include/xc.h`

Comment: the env variables are set by sourcing an script including the following comments: `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `export LIBRARY_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH`, and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` where `$VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/.../mat`

Comment: compiling with direct `-I` works obviously, but there are following errors such as `undefined reference to `xc_version'` ... which shows the libraries too are not linked, but that's another problem

Comment: the main problem for now is that the compiler seemingly can't find a file which is clearly in its path

Comment: Your description points to a problem with where you are exporting the environment variables. That must be done in your `.bashrc` if you are not launching `gcc` within a subshell in the file that actually does the export. Remember, an export can only effect the current environment (never the environment of its parent process) Also your `$VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/.../mat` should not have a `'$'`. Either try exporting from `.bashrc` or give them on the command line, e.g. `VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/.../mat; export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH ... gcc -options files libraries -o outfile`

Comment: What happens if you change that to `#include "xc.h"`

Comment: the 'export' statement is missing the trailing "/include"  so the compiler is looking at a directory above where the header file is actually located.  Also, each of the directory path items above the actual 'include' directory need to have the `x` property enabled